# Change contents of iframe when can't be loaded

Tags: html, iframe

Is there a way to display a different content (e.g. a image) when the content of a iframe cannot be loaded, because the website does not load? 
Say when a iframe shows a website but it can't load it can display an error?

Answer (score 0):

it depends, if the iframe does not load because the site is not available for display in an iframe, then it is complicated, but if the iframe does not load simply because the browser does not support them, or there is a url issue, then try
    <.iframe src="http://www.example">messege or image link here<./iframe>
I doubt this is the best solution, but it works for me!